# Cannot use shopify admin api in a reactjs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify

I want to create an application to manage orders without Shopify.com.

But as soon as I import the package with `npm install @shopify/shopify-api`, React presents me with an endless number of breaking changes, with one of those shown below. Does anyone know how I can work around this? Going back in the react-script version has only presented a different set of errors.

```
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Comment: He, did you figure this out? It's happening in my react app too!

Comment: No! Unfortunately, I have not found anything yet! @HalesEnchanted